# The problem with the launch of the epiR package

Tags: r

please could you help me to solve the problem with the launch of the epiR package?
I installed this package from CRAN via RStudio. The installation went fine, but when I try to run this package, I get the following message:

`> library(epiR)`
`Download required package: survival`
`Error: Failed to load package or namespace for 'epiR':  .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'units', details:  call: ud_init(path)  error: no database found!`

Tell me, please: what is the problem and how to solve it? Other packages (including those installed today) do not have this problem.

Comment: The documentation <https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/epiR/epiR.pdf> says:

  Depends R (>= 3.0.0), survival

So you need R >= 3.0.0 and the survival package:

`install.packages("survival")
library(survival)
library(epiR)`

Comment: Thank you! But I use R.4.1.2, and the "survival" package is pre-installed. Unfortunately the problem is not solved.

Comment: The problem is solved: `install.packages("udunits2")
library(udunits2)
library(units)
library(epiR)`